# Decimal causing issues when not physcially typed in by the user

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am having a issue with entitys and saving I am wanting to update a value of a record so i am doing the following.

I use the following in other oens but its not working here some reason to save the record it says that the key already exists.

```
_dal.portalEntities.Entry(_custInfo).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
_dal.portalEntities.SaveChanges();
_dal.portalEntities.Entry(_custInfo).Reload();
```

Here is my main routine

```
tblPortalUser _users; 
_users = _dal.GetUserRecordByEmail(_myuser.EmailAddress.ToLower());
//password is the same warn the user as current 
 if (PasswordHash.ValidatePassword(password.Text, _users.password) == true)
{    
    lblerror.Text = "Password choose a password you have not used before";
    }else
 lblerror.Text = "Current Password is invalid.";
            // if password is the same as the confirm password then proceed if not warn the user
 if (password.Text == confirmpass.Text)
 {
   _users.password = PasswordHash.HashPassword(password.Text);
  _dal.portalEntities.SaveChanges();
 //lets send out the verification codes for the email and sms
   _notifications.sendNotification(new Guid(portalbl.BLConstants.resetPasswordEmail), _custInfo.firstName + " " + _custInfo.lastName, "", _custInfo.email.ToLower(), "", "", portalbl.BLConstants.portalNotifications.Email, "");
 Response.Redirect(@"~\myaccount\logout.aspx", false);
 }
```

GetUserRecordByEmail

```
public tblPortalUser GetUserRecordByEmail(string Email)
    {
        try
        {
            tblPortalUser _user;

            _user = (from _users in _dal.portalEntities.tblPortalUsers
                     where _users.EmailAddress.ToLower() == Email
                     select _users).FirstOrDefault();


            return _user;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)

        {
            string inner = string.Empty;
            if (ex.InnerException != null)
            {
                inner = ex.InnerException.ToString();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**Edit 1**
The exception is showing here sorry i do not no how to include an image without a link when score is below ten

https://snag.gy/QMSzaE.jpg

Comment: can you please show  the exception so we could know what is problem and where is the exception thrown?

Comment: @TarekAboELkheir I have included a screen shot in my edit ther I am just trying to edit an existing record so i dont no what the issue is being to be quite honest

Answer (score 0):

From the screen shot, the exception is clear, you need first Detach the user and attach it again, and it will work

look to this article:[Attaching and Detaching Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896271(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: @Tarerk can you provide an  example please on this

Comment: @Tarerik can you please show the example not just a link